# kubectl top node `error: metrics not available yet` . Using metrics-server as Heapster Depricated

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Kubernetes not able to find metric-server api.I am using Kubernetes with Docker on Mac. I was trying to do HPA from [following example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/). However, when I execute command `kubectl get hpa`, My target still was unknown. Then I tried, `kubectl describe hpa`. Which gave me error like below:

```
  Name:                                                  php-apache
  Namespace:                                             default
  Labels:                                                <none>
  Annotations:                                           <none>
  CreationTimestamp:                                     Sun, 07 Oct 2018 12:36:31 -0700
  Reference:                                             Deployment/php-apache
  Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
    resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  <unknown> / 5%
  Min replicas:                                          1
  Max replicas:                                          10
  Conditions:
    Type           Status  Reason                   Message
    ----           ------  ------                   -------
    AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
    ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Events:
    Type     Reason                        Age               From                       Message
    ----     ------                        ----              ----                       -------
    Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  1h (x34 over 5h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
    Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       1m (x42 over 5h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
```

I am using [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) as suggested in Kubernetes documentation. I also tried doing same just using Minikube. But that also didn't work.

Running `kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes` outputs :

```
{
  "kind": "NodeMetricsList",
  "apiVersion": "metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"
  },
  "items": []
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem using metrics-server and minikube. Still, it's an issue if using Kubernetes with Docker for Mac

Comment: Could you please describe your solution as an answer to this question? It might be helpful for other community members.

Comment: First I changed my context of Kubernetes to Minikube. Then I enabled metrics-server and disabled heapster in minikube.
`minikube addons disable metrics-server`.
 `minikube addons enable metrics-server`. 
I found this (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/) resource helpful.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use official metrics server - https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

If you use one master node, run this command to create the `metrics-server`:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

If you have HA (High availability) cluster, use this:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/high-availability.yaml
```

Then use can use `kubectl top nodes` or `kubectl top pods -A` and get something like:

```
NAME          CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
```

Comment: As of 2024-03-31, the HA manifest adds a 2nd replica, pod anti affinity, and a pod disruption budget

Answer (score 14):

Use the below command in your cluster to setup Metrics Server:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pythianarora/total-practice/master/sample-kubernetes-code/metrics-server.yaml
```

This should work just fine.

I turned off TLS in metrics-server and it started working after so I updated the YAML and reposted.

Comment: Not work, use `kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pythianarora/total-practice/master/sample-kubernetes-code/metrics-server.yaml`

Comment: Hello Denis, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected it in the original post as well.

Comment: This works even for K8S version 1.23 hence upvoted.

Comment: The only one that worked so far, tried several

Answer (score 9):

**Solution(if using Minikube):**

*Changed context of Kubernetes to Minikube*.

*Enabled metrics-server and Disabled heapster in minikube.*

`minikube addons disable heapster`

`minikube addons enable metrics-server`

*Deploy metrics-server in your cluster using the following steps:*

`git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git`

`cd metrics-server`

`kubectl create -f deploy/1.7/` (if Kubernetes version 1.7)

**OR**

`kubectl create -f deploy/1.8+/`(if Kubernetes version 1.8+)

Start `minikube dashboad` and `minikube service [your service]`.

Try `kubectl top node`.

I found this (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/) resource helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a late answer, but I have had some issues with Docker Kubernetes and Autoscaler myself without finding a good answer on the internet. After many days of debugging, I found out that there were some connectivity issues with the  `metrics-server` (couldn't connect to the pods).

I turned off TLS in `metrics-server` and it started working.. I answered my own post here if someone else is experiencing the same issue:

[Docker Kubernetes (Mac) - Autoscaler unable to find metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54106725/2291510)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the certificate,
Update the yaml's deployment section which you downloaded to install metrics-server as,

Add this part in the file at: `--kubelet-insecure-tls`

```
      containers:
      - name: metrics-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.3.7
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

Complete Deployment will look like this now:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metrics-server
  template:
    metadata:
      name: metrics-server
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: metrics-server
      volumes:
      # mount in tmp so we can safely use from-scratch images and/or read-only containers
      - name: tmp-dir
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: metrics-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.3.7
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - --kubelet-insecure-tls
          - --cert-dir=/tmp
          - --secure-port=4443
        ports:
        - name: main-port
          containerPort: 4443
          protocol: TCP
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-dir
          mountPath: /tmp
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using the latest `metrics-server` on your Kubernetes cluster. The below command helped me.

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

reference link: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

Answer (score 0):

I used kubernetes in DigitalOcean and this worked:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

Comment: If you want to say thanks for the two existing answers which provide this solution please wait for the privilege to upvote them ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713681/7733418                   
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67931754/7733418 ) and delete this post meanwhile. If you intend to contribute a new insight please [edit] according to [answer] to make that more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your /home dir
  `cd /home`
- Pull the latest yaml manifest from GitHub repo
  `wget -O metrics-server.yaml https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml`
- Open the yaml manifest file `vim metrics-server.yaml`
- Press `i` to get into the insert mode
- Add the `--kubelet-insecure-tls` flag under template.spec.containers section
  [flag addition image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k2U1.png)
- Press `esc` then type `:wq` and press `enter` to save the changes
- Apply the changes made to yaml manifest to install the metrics server
  `kubectl apply -f metrics-server.yaml`

Answer (score -1):

When using minikube 1.4.0, there is no need to do anything else than `minikube start`: `kubectl top node/pod` should work out-of-the box.