# Docker Kubernetes (Mac) - Autoscaler unable to find metrics

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have installed a local instance of Kubernetes via Docker on my Mac.

Following the [walkthrough](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) on how to activate autoscaling on a deployment I have experienced an issue. The autoscaler can't read the metrics.

When I am running `kubectl describe hpa` the current cpu usage comes back as **unknown / 50%** with the warnings:

> Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric:
>   horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu:
>   unable to fetch metrics from API: the server could not find the
>   requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
>
> Warning FailedComputeMetricsReplicas 
>   horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to
>   get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from API: the
>   server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)

I have installed the metrics-server via `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git`and installed it with `kubectl create -f deploy/1.8+`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I finally got it working..
Here are the full steps I took to get things working:

1. Have Kubernetes running within Docker
2. Delete any previous instance of metrics-server from your Kubernetes instance with `kubectl delete -n kube-system deployments.apps metrics-server`
3. Clone metrics-server with `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git`
4. Edit the file **deploy/1.8+/metrics-server-deployment.yaml** to override the default command by adding a **command** section that didn't exist before. The new section will instruct metrics-server to allow for an insecure communications session (don't verify the certs involved). Do this only for Docker, and not for production deployments of metrics-server:

   ```
   containers:
   - name: metrics-server
       image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
       command:
         - /metrics-server
         - --kubelet-insecure-tls
   ```
5. Add metrics-server to your Kubernetes instance with `kubectl create -f deploy/1.8+` (if errors with the .yaml, write this instead: `kubectl apply -f deploy/1.8+`)
6. Remove and add the autoscaler to your deployment again. It should now show the current cpu usage.

**EDIT July 2020:**

Most of the above steps hold true except the [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) has changed and that file does not exist anymore.

The repo now recommends installing it like this:

```
apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.6/components.yaml
```

So we can now download this file,

```
curl -L https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.6/components.yaml --output components.yaml
```

add `--kubelet-insecure-tls` under `args` (L88) to the `metrics-server` deployment and run

```
kubectl apply -f components.yaml
```

Comment: That didn't work for me on Windows. I am still getting unknown/50%

Comment: @DavidBrossard I feel you. Did you find the fix yet?

Comment: It eventually did but I cannot remember why. Maybe I just had to wait for it to pick it up

Comment: Still not working on windows as @David mentioned. Also the command 
"kubectl top nodes" is not working as well.

Comment: But after some time, or after the cluster is restarted, the metrics will appear and then, both HPA and top commands will work.

Comment: Can you please provide further information on how you managed to install metrics on Windows nodes? I am using Windows Server march 2019 and when pulling "k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.3" I constantly get the message: "image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform". Do you have some insights or a reference to somewhere guiding how to properly set it up on Windows node?

Comment: Your steps are what it took for me as well. Unable to find this documented anywhere else except here, so thanks for posting it.

Comment: Thanks turtle, you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 8):

For who are use Internal-IP here may work for you. Follow @Mr.Turtle above at step 4. add more one command.

```
  containers:
  - name: metrics-server
    image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.3
    command:
      - /metrics-server
      - --kubelet-insecure-tls
      - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

Answer (score 4):

We upgraded to AWS EKS version 1.13.7 and that's when we started having problems with HPA, It turns out on my deployment I had to specified a value for  `resources.requests.cpu=200m` and the HPA started working for me.

Comment: Should this be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue while using my kubernetes kubeadm lab and the updated procedure is here
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

This solved the issue:
horizontal-pod-autoscaler unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes/removed.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has problems fixing this issue, this helped me fix it on minikube:

I had 2 deployments with the same label, something like this:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web

---

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: database
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
```

I renamed the label and matchLabels of the database (e.g. to app: db), then deleted both deployments and applied the new config - et voilà it worked. (after hours of trying to solve the problem..)

Further informations to this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79365

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed over EKS and i was facing the same issue.

```
muhasan@admins-MacBook-Pro devops % kubectl get hpa
NAME                     REFERENCE                           TARGETS                         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
backend-iam-deployment   Deployment/backend-iam-deployment   36278272/100Mi, <unknown>/50%   1         10        1          10m
```

in my deployment i just specified resources and that helped me to get HPA running

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-iam-deployment
  labels:
    app: backend-iam-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-iam-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-iam-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend-iam-deployment
        image: <imagename>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 10 
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 5
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: us-east-1-ecr-registry
```

After applying resource limit to my deployment HPA started working for me.

```
muhasan@admins-MacBook-Pro fx.identitymanagement % kubectl get hpa
NAME                     REFERENCE                           TARGETS                  MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
backend-iam-deployment   Deployment/backend-iam-deployment   23216128/100Mi, 1%/50%   1         10        1          24m
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the only deployment of metrics-server that worked for hpa, is this one that I share with you, I tried it with docker-desktop

[this is a modification of a solution i found, which i shared for another repo](https://github.com/thelman/peladonerd/blob/metrics-2023-kubernetes/kubernetes/5/metrics-2023/desktop-metric.yaml)

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.