# Get metrics from pod with docker for mac

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, docker-for-mac

I try to use `Horizontal Pod Autosclaer` for `nginx` pod.

When I describe my hpa I have this message `horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource`

I use **docker for mac**. I don't know if it can have an impact

**My deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-app
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     run: demo-app
 replicas: 1
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       run: demo-app
   spec:
  containers:
    - name: demo-app
      image: my-demo-app:v3
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 250m
        limits:
          cpu: 300m
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**My HPA**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
 name: demo-app-hpa
 namespace: default
spec:
 scaleTargetRef:
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   name: demo-app
 minReplicas: 1
 maxReplicas: 3
 targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 3
```

Output of **kubectl get hpa** command :

```
NAME           REFERENCE             TARGETS        MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
demo-app-hpa   Deployment/demo-app   <unknown>/3%   1         3         1          20m
```

Output of `kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` command

```
{"kind":"APIResourceList","apiVersion":"v1","groupVersion":"metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","resources":[{"name":"nodes","singularName":"","namespaced":false,"kind":"NodeMetrics","verbs":["get","list"]},{"name":"pods","singularName":"","namespaced":true,"kind":"PodMetrics","verbs":["get","list"]}]}
```

I configure metric-server with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106725/docker-kubernetes-mac-autoscaler-unable-to-find-metrics) but not work

`Scaling active` is set to False. I think it's the problem but I don't know how change value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing metrics server.

> The HorizontalPodAutoscaler normally fetches metrics from a series of aggregated APIs (`metrics.k8s.io`, `custom.metrics.k8s.io`, and `external.metrics.k8s.io`). The `metrics.k8s.io` API is usually provided by metrics-server, which needs to be launched separately. See [metrics-server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/core-metrics-pipeline/#metrics-server) for instructions. The HorizontalPodAutoscaler can also fetch metrics directly from Heapster.

You can check if there are metrics deployed by `kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

To install [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) just clone the repo and run `kubectl create -f deploy/1.8+/`

If you still have the issue I recommend checking [Docker Kubernetes (Mac) - Autoscaler unable to find metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106725/docker-kubernetes-mac-autoscaler-unable-to-find-metrics).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this without success. When I describe my HPA I have : **ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: failed to get pod resource metrics: the server could not find the requested resource (get services http:heapster:)**

Comment: @M.Hol have you followed all the steps mentioned in here [54106725](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106725/docker-kubernetes-mac-autoscaler-unable-to-find-metrics). Removing previous metrics-server and removing and adding autoscaler again?

Comment: When I use `kubectl top pods` I get CPU .. But not with `HPA`

Comment: @M.Hol `The top command allows you to see the resource consumption for nodes or pods.` which can be read on [kubectl-top man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-top)